# For a C++ string s, is s[s.size()] legal and always equal to '\0'?

Tags: c++, string

If `s[s.size()]=='\0'`, then it is convenient to treat it  as a sentinel for some algorithm. I did a test and it's always equal to `'\0'`, but some books says it's illegal to access `s[s.size()]`.

Comment: In C++, just because something works doesn't mean it's legal.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that will give a reference to a zero-valued character, as specified by the C++11 standard:

> Requires: `pos <= size()`.
>
> Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.

where `charT()` is a value-constructed character, which will have the value zero. `T` is presumably a typo for `charT`. The C++14 draft (and presumably the final standard) says the same thing, with the typo fixed.

If you have a book that says otherwise, burn it or sell it to your enemies.